# Specifying order in list of multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to Run a simulation but I'm having trouble storing multiple dataframes called "data_i" in a list ordering by i. I start with a df called "data_", which has data from 1901 to 2032 (132 rows). I apply a loop to create one dataframe per row called data_1, data_2,data_3,...,data_132 (row of 2032 is stored in data_132). Finally, I store all this dataframes in a list and use lapply to create a column in each dataframe. Here is a reproducible example:

```
#Main dataframe
time <- 1901:2032
b <- 1:132
data_ <- data.frame(time,b)


#Loop for creating data_i where i goes from 1 to 132
simulations <- 10000
for (i in 1:132) {
  assign(paste("data_",i, sep = ""), as.data.frame( sapply(data_[i,], function(n) rep(n,simulations)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )) 
}

#Store all dataframes in list (**I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE**)
data_names<-str_extract(ls(), '^data_[[:digit:]]{1,3}$')[!is.na(str_extract(ls(), '^data_[[:digit:]]{1,3}$'))]
dataframes<-lapply(data_names, function(x)get(x))

#Create a new column in each dataframe
new_list <- lapply(dataframes, function(x) cbind(x, production = as.numeric(runif(simulations, min = 50, max = 100))))

#Create data_newi in environnment                                                
list2env(setNames(new_list,paste0("data_new", seq_along(dataframes))), 
         envir = parent.frame())
```

The code runs but the problem is that the order of the dataframes is not data_1, data_2,data_3,...,data_132 but data_1,data_10,data_100,data_101...This generates that data_names stores this values in that order. This will lead to, for example, 2032 not being in data_new132 as I would want it to be.

Does anybody knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*(This is a dupe, and it is closed appropriately. I encourage you to look at the dupe-questions for reference. Here is a customization of it specific to your starting point.)*

`ls()` defaults to `sorted=TRUE`, which means your names are sorted alphabetically. That kind of sort is not the same as numeric sort.

If you want a list of frames to begin with, then make a list of frames, don't go through the dance of `assign`/`get`. And once you have it in a list, keep it there, and use `lapply` and its related functions to do your tasks on all frames.

```r
time <- 1901:2032
b <- 1:132
data_ <- data.frame(time,b)

simulations <- 10
ints <- seq_len(132)
set.seed(2021)
new_list <- lapply(setNames(ints, paste0("data_", ints)), function(i) {
  cbind(
    data_[rep(i, simulations),],
    production = runif(simulations, min = 50, max = 100)
  )
})
length(new_list)
# [1] 132
new_list[1:2]
# $data_1
#     time b production
# 1   1901 1   72.56337
# 1.1 1901 1   89.18899
# 1.2 1901 1   85.48411
# 1.3 1901 1   69.08721
# 1.4 1901 1   81.81619
# 1.5 1901 1   85.06730
# 1.6 1901 1   82.02195
# 1.7 1901 1   63.33399
# 1.8 1901 1   90.77108
# 1.9 1901 1   99.14934
# $data_2
#     time b production
# 2   1902 2   51.36335
# 2.1 1902 2   91.87452
# 2.2 1902 2   80.16204
# 2.3 1902 2   78.37267
# 2.4 1902 2   91.00264
# 2.5 1902 2   62.57856
# 2.6 1902 2   75.27470
# 2.7 1902 2   93.37691
# 2.8 1902 2   97.90908
# 2.9 1902 2   77.28489
```